# Real world objects

Tags: oop, object, concept

If we treat **tree** as an **object** then what will be its leaf and branches?
Similarly, if we treat **dog** as an **object** then what will be its legs,mouth and eyes?

Comment: they would be other collections of various objects organized in a hierarchical manner.

Comment: This is a fine conceptual OOP question - no reason to close.

Comment: @AlexWeinstein - Conceptual questions are more appropriate for programmers.se.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tree HAS a set of branches. Each branch HAS a set of leaves.

That is, (pseudocode)

```
class Tree {
    Branch[] branches;
}

class Branch {
    Leaf[] leaves;
}


class Leaf {

}
```

Similarly with the dog: a dog HAS a collection of eyes; it also has a collection of legs; and it has a mouth.

```
class Dog {
    Leg[] legs;
    Mouth mouth;
    Eye[] eyes;
}
```

Comment: Ya i got that they follow HAS-A relationship, but it is when we treat dog as class, or object also have HAS-A relationship with any data member? please be more specific.

Comment: An object DOG has an array of Leg objects.